# .Dat file to dataset

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have a .dat file that I need to import into a datatable. I am using .net framework 4.5 and it delimited by ~. How do I import this? I tried

```
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + fileName;
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
OleDbDataAdapter dsCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
//Fill the DataSet object
dsCmd.Fill(myData, "Packets");
```

Please help

Comment: what was the error or unexpected result you received?

Comment: See this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109360/how-to-specify-the-delimiter-when-importing-csv-files-via-oledb-in-c-sharp

Comment: This is the error I received. **Cannot update. Database or object is read-only**

Comment: What is the filename? I found these two links which may be relevant : https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;304206 and http://access.mvps.org/access/bugs/bugs0046.htm

Comment: Thanks for you response. Filename is Test.dat ... The links that you have posted mentions that .dat format is not valid. But that's how we receive the file. @PaulF

Comment: Ooops - could have answered that myself by looking at the question. The first link suggests renaming the file before use - would that be an option or copying it to a temporary file with csv (or other valid) extension & then deleting after. Or solution 3 is a registry modification if you are able to do that.