# Read .csv to datatable and fill a datagridview

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, datatable

I have a .csv file and I'd like to read it into a datagridview (each value into an each column).
I read this file with block note and I see that each value is divided by ";"

I tried to set a datatable but it's not working. This is my code:

```
string FileName = @"C:\mydir\testcsv.csv";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
conn.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName), conn);    
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
adapter.Fill(ds);

conn.Close();

dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;
```

I don't understand where's the error.

Comment: @MichalHainc Grid empty

Comment: See [Schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx) for specifying delimiter, decimal symbol, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked for me as it is.

I just added one line to the datasource assignment after looking inside the dataset, I saw just one table is inside with name "Table" so I assigned the datamember of the datagridview:

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Table";
```

Anyway if I used ';' separator, all the values were in one column... With ',' comma separator it works ok.

[image: It looks like this]

The complete code of the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FileName = @"C:\mydir\testcsv.csv";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
                   ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " +
                     Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) +
                     "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");

            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
                   ("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName), conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            conn.Close();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Table";
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of the csv file:

```
abc,123
def,456
ijk,789
lmn,111213
```

For semicolon delimited files you need to add an ini file in your folder containing the csv file. How to do it exactly is described here:

[How to specify the delimiter when importing CSV files via OLEDB in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109360/how-to-specify-the-delimiter-when-importing-csv-files-via-oledb-in-c-sharp)

For decimal delimiter symbol you have to add  the

```
DecimalSymbol
```

directive to your Jet ini file.

See the full ini file capabilities documented in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Can you post your working code? so I can copy and paste. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not working. My values are not just in a column into my csv file. And the separate symbol is ";". Could be this the problem? :)

Comment: ok, it's working but I have just a little problem: in three columns values are like this: "1.50", but this code delete "."   How Can I keep it?

Comment: Done, but please come in chat

Answer (score 2):

I use this function by long, long time, after: yourgrid.datasource = function result.

```
        public static DataTable CsvDb(string filename, string separatorChar)
    {
        var table = new DataTable("Filecsv");
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string line;
            var i = 0;
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
                    var values = line.Split(new[] { separatorChar }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    var row = table.NewRow();
                    for (var colNum = 0; colNum < values.Length; colNum++)
                    {
                        var value = values[colNum];
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            table.Columns.Add(value, typeof(String));
                        }
                        else
                        { row[table.Columns[colNum]] = value; }
                    }
                    if (i != 0) table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string cErr = ex.Message;
                    //if you need the message error
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Try...

Comment: It's few time that I am using C# so... How can I add this in my datagridview? thanks :)

Comment: Datatable oDt = CsvDb("youfilecsv", ";");
datagridview.Datasource = oDt;
oDt.Dispose;

Comment: Performance of this code is impressive.